# WooCommerce product reviews not showing in product detail page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have developed a very basic WordPress theme and installed WooCommerce. Every functionality of WooCommerce is perfectly working in my theme.

**Issue: Only in product detailed page, product  reviews tab, reviews listing and review form are missing.**

Under WooCommerce settings reviews settings is enabled and in WordPress default discussion settings is also enabled.

For product detailed page I use 'single-product.php' template with following code.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**Note: When I add the following in my functions.php then entire store and WooCommerce stop working and everything gets distorted.**

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: First question why you use above code when woocomerce has some other code?

Comment: Any luck enabling reviews without using "add_theme_support()"?

Answer (score 6):

if you have done code perfectly but please do not to forgot the Enable reviews option from the admin side in product.

Here I have explain the steps for your reference.
In admin side product data -> Advanced -> Enable Reviews

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this function and also check the comment is enable?
Follow this link
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

```
  function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: I already tried this function and adding this distorted everything of my WooCommerce store and I was unable to access product details page then.

Comment: disabling comments will hide review form on product pages